# Combining Bootstrap & custom JS functions for form validation

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm building a form that has multiple validation rules for most of its fields. Initially, I had used [Bootstrap form validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) since I really like the way it handles error messages and/or valid input messages to the user. This was working fine while applying all the input constraints straight into the `<input>` tags of the HTML page and using the recommended event handler:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

Now my issue comes with combining the validation logic provided inside the `<input>` html elements as well as applying extra validation through JS code when calling submit on the form.

For example, I may have a regex pattern already applied to the input html element but I also want to check for specific words, length and some other constraints through JS specifically. Is there any way to combine these two approaches?

In Bootstrap's [how it works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#how-it-works) section, they mention the `was-validated` class, but I'm not sure if or how to use it to render an input as invalid if it fails the JS validation but passes the HTML pattern match, for example.

An example of a few form fields and my js code would be as follows:

```
'use-strict';

function hideElement(elementID) {
  $(`#${elementID}`).attr('hidden', true);
}

function showElement(elementID) {
  $(`#${elementID}`).attr('hidden', false);
}


function restoreDefaultInvalidMessages() {
  $("#passwd-invalid-feedback").text('Ο κωδικος σας πρέπει να είναι μεταξύ 8 και 12 χαρακτήρων και να περιέχει τουλάχιστον έναν ειδικό χαρακτήρα (#?!@$%^&*-).');
  $("#passwd-verif-invalid-feedback").text('Ο κωδικος σας πρέπει να είναι μεταξύ 8 και 12 χαρακτήρων και να περιέχει τουλάχιστον έναν ειδικό χαρακτήρα (#?!@$%^&*-).');
}

function markFieldAsValid(elementID) {
  $(`#${elementID}`).addClass("is-valid");
  $(`#${elementID}`).removeClass("is-invalid");
}

function markFieldAsInvalid(elementID) {
  $(`#${elementID}`).addClass("is-invalid");
  console.log($(`#${elementID}`));
  $(`#${elementID}`).removeClass("is-valid");
}

function isPasswordValid(password) {
  if (passwordContainsInvalidWords(password)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function isUndergradEmailValid(email, university) {

  if (university == "uoc" && email.endsWith('uoc.gr')) {
    return true;
  } else if (university == "tuc" && email.endsWith('tuc.gr')) {
    return true;
  } else if (university == "helmepa" && email.endsWith('helmepa.gr')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// date params should be date objects
function isStudentPassDateRangeValid(startDate, endDate, studentType) {
  // comparison works because date objects store the date as a timestamp in ms
  if (endDate > startDate) {
    let passValidityYearsRange = endDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear();
    if (studentType == 'undergrad' && passValidityYearsRange <= 6) {
      return true;
    } else if (studentType == 'postgrad' && passValidityYearsRange <= 2) {
      return true;
    } else if (studentType == 'doctorate' && passValidityYearsRange <= 5) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

(function () {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
      console.log('adding submit listener');
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        console.log('submit listener called');
        let isFormValid = true;
        //restoreDefaultInvalidMessages();

        console.log('called before checks');

        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          isFormValid = false;
        }

        let formData = new FormData(form);

        let password = formData.get('passw');
        let passwordVerif = formData.get('passw_verif');
      
        if (!isPasswordValid(password)) {
          markFieldAsInvalid("fpsw");
          $("#passwd-invalid-feedback").text('Ο κωδικός δεν μπορεί να περιέχει τις εξής λέξεις (helmepa, uoc, tuc)!');
          //hideElement('passwd-valid-feedback');
          isFormValid = false;
        }
        else {
          hideElement('passwd-invalid-feedback');
          showElement('passwd-valid-feedback');
        }
      
        if (!isPasswordValid(passwordVerif)) {
          markFieldAsInvalid("fpswconfirmation");
          $("#passwd-verif-invalid-feedback").text('Ο κωδικός δεν μπορεί να περιέχει τις εξής λέξεις (helmepa, uoc, tuc)!');
          hideElement('passwd-verif-valid-feedback');
          isFormValid = false;
        } else {
          hideElement('passwd-verif-invalid-feedback');
          showElement('passwd-verif-valid-feedback');
        }
      
        if (password != passwordVerif) {
          markFieldAsInvalid("fpsw");
          markFieldAsInvalid("fpswconfirmation");
          $("#passwd-invalid-feedback").text('Οι κωδικοί δεν ταιριάζουν!');
          $("#passwd-verif-invalid-feedback").text('Οι κωδικοί δεν ταιριάζουν!');
          hideElement('passwd-valid-feedback');
          hideElement('passwd-verif-valid-feedback');
          showElement('passwd-invalid-feedback');
          showElement('passwd-verif-invalid-feedback')
          isFormValid = false;
        }
      
        // apply undergrad checks if needed
        if ($('#fusertype').value() == 'undergrad') {
          let email = $('#femail').value();
          let university = $('#funiversity').value();
          let studentType = $('#fstudenttype').value();
          let studentPassStartDate = document.getElementById('fidstartdate').valueAsDate;
          let studentPassEndDate = document.getElementById('fidenddate').valueAsDate;
          if(!isUndergradEmailValid(email,university) || !isStudentPassDateRangeValid(studentPassStartDate,studentPassEndDate,studentType)) {
            isFormValid = false;
          }
        }
      
        form.classList.add('was-validated');

      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();


function markUndergradFieldsAsRequired() {
  let fieldIds = ['fstudenttype', 'fidnum', 'fidstartdate', 'fidenddate', 'funiversity', 'fdep'];
  fieldIds.forEach((id) => {
    $(`#${id}`).attr('required', true);
    $(`label[for="${id}"`).append(' *');
  });
}

function unmarkUndergradRequiredFields() {
  let fieldIds = ['fstudenttype', 'fidnum', 'fidstartdate', 'fidenddate', 'funiversity', 'fdep'];
  fieldIds.forEach((id) => {
    $(`#${id}`).attr('required', false);
    $(`label[for="${id}"`).text($(`label[for="${id}"`).text().replace(' *', ''));
  });
}

function hideUndergradFields() {
  $('#undergrad-type-col').attr('hidden', true);
  $('#undergrad-pass-row').attr('hidden', true);
  $('#undergrad-pass-dates-row').attr('hidden', true);
  $('#undergrad-univ-dep-row').attr('hidden', true);
}

function showUndergradFields() {
  $('#undergrad-type-col').attr('hidden', false);
  $('#undergrad-pass-row').attr('hidden', false);
  $('#undergrad-pass-dates-row').attr('hidden', false);
  $('#undergrad-univ-dep-row').attr('hidden', false);
}

function updateAddressFieldBasedOnUserType(type) {
  if (type === "undergrad") {
    $("#faddr-label").text('Διεύθυνση Οικίας');
  } else if (type === "lib-admin") {
    $("#faddr-label").text('Διεύθυνση Βιβλιοθήκης');
  }
}

function showLibrarianFields() {
  $("#lib-info-row").attr("hidden", false);
  $("#flib-info").attr("required", true);
  $("#lib-name-col").attr("hidden", false);
  $("#flib-name").attr("required", true);
}

function hideLibrarianFields() {
  $("#lib-info-row").attr("hidden", true);
  $("#flib-info").attr("required", false);
  $("#lib-name-col").attr("hidden", true);
  $("#flib-name").attr("required", false);
}

function onUserTypeSelected(type) {
  if (type === "undergrad") {
    showUndergradFields();
    markUndergradFieldsAsRequired();
    updateAddressFieldBasedOnUserType("undergrad");
    hideLibrarianFields();
  } else if (type === "lib-admin") {
    showLibrarianFields();
    unmarkUndergradRequiredFields();
    updateAddressFieldBasedOnUserType("lib-admin");
    hideUndergradFields();
  } else if (type === "") { // default option value
    unmarkUndergradRequiredFields();
    showUndergradFields();
    updateAddressFieldBasedOnUserType("undergrad");
    hideLibrarianFields();
  }
}

function onPasswordInputUpdate(password) {
  let specialSymbols = new Set();
  let containsUppercase = false;
  let containsLowercase = false;
  let numOfDigits = 0;
  let passwordStrength;
  let meterVal = 0;

  // perform strength status constraints
  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(password.charAt(i))) {
      numOfDigits++;
    }
    if (isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) containsUppercase = true;
    else if (isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) containsLowercase = true;
    else if (isSpecialChar(password.charAt(i))) {
      specialSymbols.add(password.charAt(i));
    }
  }

  // infer password strength
  if (numOfDigits >= password.length) {
    passwordStrength = "Weak";
    meterVal = 1;
  } else if (specialSymbols.size >= 2 && containsLowercase && containsUppercase) {
    passwordStrength = "Strong";
    meterVal = 3;
  } else {
    passwordStrength = "Medium";
    meterVal = 2;
  }

  // update DOM elements
  document.getElementById("password-strength-meter").value = meterVal;
  document.getElementById("password-strength-text").innerHTML = passwordStrength;
}

function onTogglePassword(icon, fieldId) {
  const fieldType = $("#" + fieldId).attr("type") === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
  $("#" + fieldId).attr("type", fieldType);
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash'); // change icon
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="registration-form">
            <form class="needs-validation" name="signup-form"
                novalidate>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <label for="fusername">Όνομα Χρήστη *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                id="fusername"
                                placeholder="Your username"
                                minlength="8" required>
                            <div class="valid-feedback">
                                Όλα τέλεια!
                            </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Το όνομα χρήστη πρέπει να περιέχει
                                τουλάχιστον 8 χαρακτήρες.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <label for="femail">Διεύθυνση Email *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control"
                                id="femail"
                                placeholder="example@domain.com"
                                required>
                            <div class="valid-feedback">
                                Όλα τέλεια!
                            </div>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                Η διεύθυνση email πρέπει να είναι μια
                                έγκυρη διεύθυνση.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn
                    btn-primary mb-2" onclick="onSubmit()">Εγγραφή</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And in the `onSubmit()` JS function there would be additional validation checks. Without bootstrap, this would be simply done by returning false/true depending on the validation results. But I don't know how to combine this with Bootstrap's validation logic and their event listener.

Comment: I don't see any element with `needs-validation` class. Did you put all the code?

Comment: Can you provide your JS validation methods as well as your onSubmit function. From the code blocks you provided we cannot see any JS input validation nor your onSubmit function.

Comment: @mlegrix You're absolutely right, I messed up my bad. I have added the anonymous function that handles the validation along with the rest of the utility methods just in case they are needed.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 The HTML file is too large for S.O. to support, so I couldn't paste the whole thing and decided to add a sample of the fields. They are enclosed in a `<form class="needs-validation" id="signup-form" name="signup-form" novalidate>`  tag as is visible in the example.

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with what you are doing. You can combine native form validation with JS validation like you are doing. **You are only missing the `event.preventDefault()` in your `submit` event handler when your form is invalid at the end.** This will prevent the form from being sent by cancelling the event when your `isFormValid === false`. Have a look at the [MDN documentation on the subject for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail I added an answer following my last comment. Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To recap when doing client-side validation:

- You can use built-in form validation without having to rely on JavaScript.
- You can use JavaScript to fully customize your validations.

Most important of all, both are not exclusive. Both can work side by side.

The built-in form validation will be triggered automatically by the browser. You can if you choose to have control over it via the **Constraint Validation API** ([more info on that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation)).

When doing JavaScript validation however, the most important thing to remember is to **block the form from submitting when your data is invalid**. This is done by calling the `preventDefault()` method on the `event`. An example from the [MDN Form Validation documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript):

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  // if the email field is valid, we let the form submit
  if (!email.validity.valid) {
    // If it isn't, we display an appropriate error message
    showError();
    // Then we prevent the form from being sent by canceling the event
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```